# libp2p as a transport/middleware for ROS

Tags: ros, ros2

I wonder if there is an initiative or the implementation of [`libp2p`](https://github.com/libp2p/cpp-libp2p)'s pubsub feature or the entire network stack as an available transport for ROS? Do you know something about any efforts for implementing this? Does anyone have an opinion about if it is doable?